# How to force Tor Browser to use specific exit node for specific website

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Some websites are able to detect that you are using Tor network and block your connection. The most well-known example is https://google.com, which will re-direct you to a Captcha page on most exit nodes. However, sometimes you can request a new exit node and get lucky, and the website will allow you to connect.

Is there a way to force Tor Browser to always connect to a specific exit node for a certain website? For example, I want to find a "good" exit node that allows me to connect to https://google.com, and then whenever I visit that site in the future I will always connect from the "good" exit node.

I imagine this will require adding a line to my `torrc` file. The closest thing I have found are [these instructions](https://communitydocs.accessnow.org/147-Tor_force_exit_nodes.html), but this seems to be for using one exit node across ALL websites, not specific ones.

Answer (score -1):

1. Dont use Google us [DuckDuckGo.onion](https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/) or [DuckDuckGo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/)
2. Add to the Tor configuration in the: "**torrc**" this:

   EntryNodes {in} StrictNodes 1
   ExitNodes {jp} StrictNodes 1
   ExcludeNodes {de},{nl} StrictNodes 1
   ExcludeExitNodes {de},{nl} StrictNodes 1
   GeoIPExcludeUnknown 1

[List of country codes for Tor](https://b3rn3d.herokuapp.com/blog/2014/03/05/tor-country-codes/)

You can also add this:

```
NewCircuitPeriod 300
MaxCircuitDirtiness 150
ConnectionPadding 0
AvoidDiskWrites 1
```